# (React Typescript) 'Component' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Component'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I want to make routes array and apply it on useRoutes from react-router@6. Currently I am using typescript and vite. But, i got error when try to assign my component to 'element' key.

> type HelloWorld = /*unresolved*/ any
> 'HelloWorld' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof
> HelloWorld'?ts(2749)
> Parsing error: '>' expected.eslint

```
import { useRoutes, RouteObject } from "react-router-dom"

import { HelloWorld } from "@/HelloWorld"

export function Router (): ReturnType<typeof useRoutes> {
  const routes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
      path: "hello-world",
      element: <HelloWorld />
    }
  ]

  return useRoutes(routes)
}
```

Comment: What is `HelloWorld` in this context? [mcve]

Comment: @DrewReese a component, sir.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please make sure that your file has the `.tsx` file extension and is not just a `.ts` file.

Comment: You're right. I missed it. Thank you.